# Hibernate :Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jsp

i have this issue :

> Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bytecodete`.`company_links`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_company_links_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES
>   `company` (`idUser`) ON DELETE CASCADE
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE)

But i don't really understand this happens, so i will post my tables here:

```
//USER TABLE
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bytecodete`.`user`;
CREATE TABLE  `bytecodete`.`user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)

//COMPANY TABLE
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bytecodete`.`company`;
CREATE TABLE  `bytecodete`.`company` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fantasyName` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `corporateName` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cnpj` (`cnpj`),
  CONSTRAINT `company_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

// COMPANY_LINKS TABLE
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bytecodete`.`company_links`;
  CREATE TABLE  `bytecodete`.`company_links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `idCompany` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `serviceName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `link` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
   CONSTRAINT `FK_company_links_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `company` (`idUser`) 
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
   )
```

I know this exception gives when i try to insert something in an table where there's a foreign key and i don't have setup some value to this key.
But this isn't my case, here is my output:

```
11:47:30,809  INFO SessionFactoryObjectFactory:82 - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        bytecodete.user
        (email, password, type) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
11:47:30,948 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'valter.bcc@gmail.com' to parameter: 1
11:47:30,949 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'U25YM/DOl5k=' to parameter: 2
11:47:30,950 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '2' to parameter: 3
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        bytecodete.company
        (cnpj, corporateName, fantasyName, idUser) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
11:47:31,214 TRACE StringType:133 - binding '98806728000100' to parameter: 1
11:47:31,215 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'Semana da Computação e Tecnologia' to parameter: 2
11:47:31,215 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'SECOT' to parameter: 3
11:47:31,216 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '37' to parameter: 4
idCompany=37
Hibernate: 
    select
        company_.idUser,
        company_.cnpj as cnpj9_,
        company_.corporateName as corporat3_9_,
        company_.fantasyName as fantasyN4_9_ 
    from
        bytecodete.company company_ 
    where
        company_.idUser=?
11:47:31,300 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '37' to parameter: 1
11:47:31,316 TRACE StringType:172 - returning '98806728000100' as column: cnpj9_
11:47:31,316 TRACE StringType:172 - returning 'Semana da Computação e Tecnologia' as column: corporat3_9_
11:47:31,351 TRACE StringType:172 - returning 'SECOT' as column: fantasyN4_9_
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        bytecodete.company_links
        (idCompany, link, serviceName, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
11:47:31,353 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '37' to parameter: 1
11:47:31,354 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'http://www.flickr.com/services/api/' to parameter: 2
11:47:31,354 TRACE StringType:133 - binding 'Flickr' to parameter: 3
11:47:31,355 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '0' to parameter: 4
11:47:31,433  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
11:47:31,452 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bytecodete`.`company_links`, CONSTRAINT `FK_company_links_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `company` (`idUser`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Sorry guys bothering you, but i really need help with this, i don't know what's happen.

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd probably need to see some code to help you more, but just based on the INSERT statements, it looks like maybe your foreign key from `company_links` to `company` is wrong.  Your INSERT into `company_links` has a 37 for `idCompany`, and a 0 for `id`.  Your foreign key is set up on `id`, not `idCompany`, so the 37 should be set on `id`, or the foreign should be changed to `idCompany`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your parameter order mixed up.  Your insert statement is:

> ```
> insert 
> into
>     bytecodete.company_links
>     (idCompany, link, serviceName, id) 
> values
>     (?, ?, ?, ?)
> ```

And you are binding 37 to parameter 1 (idCompany), and 0 to parameter 4 (id).  The id needs to be 37, not 0.

Comment: 37 is the id of my company, and 0 is the id of my table company_links.

Comment: But your foreign key from company_links to company is on the company_links.id column.  Sounds like it should be on the idCompany column instead.